# Post String Array to APIController

Tags: c#

I am unable to work out how to post a string array to my APIController

I want to be able to send the following JSON string:

```
{"userName":"un","userPassword":"password"}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public class CheckAuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    public object Post(string[] stuff)
    {
        try
        {
            return GeneralFunctions.CheckAuthentication(stuff[0].ToString(), stuff[0].ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        }
    }
}
```

This what my post looks like in fiddler:

```
POST https://localhost:8081/CheckAuthentication HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Length: 43

{"userName":"un","userPassword":"password"}
```

But when I debug, "stuff" is always null.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: how are you posting it? you are expecting an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a javascript object(json) and not a string array.

A string array in javascript will look like this:

```
["this","is","a","string","array"]
```

and an object will look like:

```
{this:"is", a:"string", object:"ok"}
```

You will need to add a class like this:

```
class LoginData
{
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string UserPassword {get;set;}
}


public class CheckAuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    public object Post(LoginData loginData)
    {
        try
        {
            return GeneralFunctions.CheckAuthentication(loginData.Username , loginData.UserPassword );
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
        }
    }
}
```

and this should be your json post:

```
{Username : 'user', UserPassword: 'pass'}
```

Comment: `{Username`... is not [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/). It should have double quotes, like his original JSON

Comment: Your'e right, I wrote plain javascript. The json string will appear a bit different in the post data.